# How to make sure every data members of a class have been copied in its copy constructor?

Tags: c++

When a class has many data members, it is hard to figure out whether a data member is copied or not in its copy constructor.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Why do you feel that you need to figure it out?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am rewriting some legacy code, there are some classes which contain many data members, and I found that it is hard to make sure that no data member is missing in the copy constructor.

Comment: currently I copy the data members defined in the class to file A, and the statement in the copy constructor to another file B. make some changes and replacement with file A and file B, then compare these two files. It works, but I hope there is an effective way.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​ino: If you're rewriting the code, why not take the opportunity to rewrite it such that this is not a problem? :)

Comment: Quick, someone link the Rule of Zero article.

Comment: The best copy constructor is one the compiler writes for you: [Rule of Zero](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html).

Comment: @Casey Nice article!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple solution is to make sure every member type is copyable, and that there are e.g. no pointers to self or other pointers or references that require fix-ups. Then the generated copy-constructor is good enough.

Answer (score 3):

The best thing to do is to rely on the compiler generated one, and ensure the class members copy appropriately.

You can do this explicitly using `= default`: available since c++11.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create copy constructor you could use of some helper structure for which you will not create the copy constructor (leave the default one) and store the data that should be copied in the field (by value) of this type. You will then need only the one field to be copied.